# Calling iid.googleapis.com with OAuth2.0 token gives MissingIIdToken

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I am having trouble calling the endpoint listed here: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server. The response is:

```
{"error":"MissingIIdToken"}
```

I tried it multiple times and I verified the FCM registration token is correct, as well as the bearer token. This is how it looks in Insomnia:

[image]

I generated the bearer token with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging` by using https://docs.rs/yup-oauth2/latest/yup_oauth2/. I could send FCM messages to single devices without problems using this scope/token.

What am I doing wrong? The token generation is here (from [fcm_v1](https://github.com/sanath-2024/fcm_v1/blob/66c4ca0afd8bba9e79ef4375d5728e3b629a9d9f/src/client.rs#L52)):

```
async fn token(&self) -> Result<String> {
    let scopes = &["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"];

    self.authenticator
        .token(scopes)
        .await
        .map_err(|_| Error::Auth)?
        .token()
        .map(|t| t.to_string())
        .ok_or_else(|| Error::Config)
}
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Which code do you mean? I make the request through Insomnia, or do you want to see the code of the token generation?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I refreshed the FCM registration code (uninstall and reinstalled the app). I think it's a misleading error code.